# Adjusting the axisMarker mode for the Shield UI Line Polar chart

Tags: javascript, shieldui

I use a Shield UI JavaScripty chart that is in a polar layout or a polar line (“polarline”) type to be precise. 
The problem that I do have is that the axismarker won’t show but instead I do get some strange results.
For instance when I set it using this code:

```
tooltipSettings: {
  axisMarkers: {
    enabled: true,
    mode: 'x'
  }
},
```

and move the mouse over a point a radial line appears along the ones already on the chart.

When I switch the mode to y I get an additional circle within the chart area crossing the point of selection (hover).

Are there any additional settings that I need to set/enable?

Answer (score 1):

There are no additional settings to be adjusted. You are actually successfully setting the axisMarker for you polar chart. However you probably expect to have vertical/horizontal line(s) for markers - depending of the mode as in a line chart for example.
The Shield UI Polar Axis Markers are in the form of a circle (when in mode y) and in the form of a radial line (when in mode x).

To better illustrate it yourself you may colorize the markers lines using code like this one:

```
tooltipSettings: {
  axisMarkers: {
    enabled: true,
    mode: 'xy',
    width: 2,
    zIndex: 2,
    color: 'red'
  }
},
```